# I Can insert nested values in Cassandra BUT can't import from CSV file

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have this table in Cassandra :

```
CREATE TABLE footbaStatsleague (
     league int PRIMARY KEY,
     hometeam text,
     homegoal int,
     homegoalsplayer frozen<map<text,list<int>>>,
     awayteam text,
     awaygoals int,
     awaygoalsplayer frozen<map<text,list<int>>>,
     dategame timestamp,matchweek text
) WITH comment='Contains stats for europe football';
```

I can insert data without any problem :

```
INSERT INTO footbastatsleague (league, awaygoals, awaygoalsplayer,awayteam,dategame,homegoal,homegoalsplayer,hometeam,matchweek) VALUES 
(222,3,{'André Schürrle':[52,65,68]},'Chelsea',1393686000000,1,{'John Heitinga':[74]},'Fulham','MW 28');
```

If I export data with COPY footbastatsleague to 'path/football.csv'; I get this:

```
222,3,"{'Andr Schrrle': [52, 65, 68]}",Chelsea,2014-03-01 15:00:00.000+0000,1,{'John Heitinga': [74]},Fulham,MW 28
```

**But** if I try to import FROM CSV file with the same format exported before, I get this error in cql shell:

> Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse {'Andr Schrrle':
>   [52, 65, 68]} : unhashable type: 'list',  given up without retries
>   Failed to process 1 rows; failed rows written to
>   import_footballstatistics_footbastatsleague.err

And I need import from CSV more than insert row by row.

Comment: which cqlsh version are you using ? I have tested it with cqlsh v2.2.4, imported  your data without any error

Comment: [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.7 | CQL spec 3.4.2 | Native protocol v4] and it does not work.

Comment: may be it's a issue in cassandra 3.7 cqlsh, try it with cassandra 2.2.4 cqlsh